# TFS2013: where diagnostic log stored if no drop location specified?

Tags: logging, tfs, diagnostics

We recently upgrade our TFS instance from TFS2012 to TFS2013. 
On our remote build server, we got below error Randomly:

> "An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: One or more errors occurred."

Our build do not have drop location specified, so I am wondering where it was trying to copy the diagnostic log to?

I checked in TFS DB for build information, the log location is set to "#/XXXXX/logs", and the "XXXXX" is "ContainerID" of the build. But I could not find where the log is really stored.

I am also wondering if this is stored in DB or TFS server, if this will contribute to TFS performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container refers to the FileContainer service used by the build to store the drops in the DB (everything in TFS is stored in the SQL DB). You get to the drop location through the build summary page in VS or in the web UI. As for the random error, perhaps there are network issues that are preventing it from copying.

Comment: Is there any way we can disable to copy diag log to TFS DB if no drop location is specified for the build? Our build server is in remote location, the log is about 30MB for each.we do not really want to copy it in this case.

Comment: I don't know that there is a way.